# Use LaF and grepl together

Tags: r, text-processing

I would like to read in a possibly large text file and filter the relevant lines on the fly based on a regular expression. My first approach was using the package `LaF` which supports chunkwise reading and then `grepl` to filter. However, this seems not to work:

```
library(LaF)
fh <- laf_open_csv("myfile.txt", column_types="string", sep="°") 
# would be nice to declare *no* separator
fh[grepl("abc", fh[[1]]), ]
```

returns an error in `as.character.default(x)` -- no method to convert this S4 to character. It seems like `grepl` is applied to the S4 function and not to the chunks.

Is there a nice way to read text lines from a large file and filter them selectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just discovered `process_blocks`:

```
regfilter <- function(df, result) c(result, df[grepl("1745", df[[1]]),1])
process_blocks(fh, regfilter)
```

This works, now I only need to find a way to ignore separators..